# How to have a OR search while aggregating in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this query which gets the aggregation of the mentions field for all the tweets with the text "CAT DOG". How can I edit my query such that I get the aggregation for all the tweets containing either "cat" or "dog".

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
           "query": {
                "match_all": {}
           },
           "filter": {"text" : "CAT DOG"}
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "tweet": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "hashtags",
                "size" : 50
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look to [multi_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) query it has option **operator** you should set it to **or** which means that any should match.

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
       "multi_match" : {
         "query":      "CAT DOG",
         "fields":     [ "text"],
         "operator":   "or" 
     }
  },
    "aggs": {
        "tweet": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "hashtags",
                "size" : 50
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Other option in your case is bool query, but you should be aware that it will search for terms it means that if you are using default analyzer it will lowercase tokens and to match them you must lowercase user input, also you are responsible to split tokens from user input.

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
      "bool" : {
      "should" : [
        { "term" : { "text": "cat" } },
        { "term" : { "text" : "dog" } }
      ],
    }
  }
  },
    "aggs": {
        "tweet": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "hashtags",
                "size" : 50
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [should](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query.
If something not clear fill free to ask.
Please attention to elasticsearch version.